# Dependency is not satisfiable ibqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.7.4)

Tags: archive

I am trying to install **b1freearchiver_current_stable_i386**, but, I get an error that:
**b1freearchiver: Depends: libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.7.4)** but
**4:4.7.0-0ubuntu2~lucid1~ppa2** is to be installed
after installing libqt4-dbus iget this one :
**This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.7.4)**
Is there any way to get around this ?
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the higher version? 
Try installing [libqt4-dbus (4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libqt4-dbus)
package. Download the package and install it by giving the command

**sudo dpkg -i "package name".deb**